# Retrieving a Google user's email address (OAuth2 + PHP)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin

OK so I have tried literally everything I've read and I still can't come up with a way to retrieve a logged in Google user's email address.

This is my code ($client is a HTTP client):

```
$response = $client->post($this->getAccessTokenURL(), ['query' => [
    'client_id' => $this->getClientID(),
    'client_secret' => $this->getClientSecret(),
    'code' => $params['code'],
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'scope' => 'email'
]]);

$data = json_decode($response->getBody());

$response = $client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me', ['query' => [
    'access_token' => $data->access_token
]]);

$data = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

The result contains TONS of data, but not the email. I've read everywhere that the "email" scope was correct for that purpose, but to no avail.

Result sample:

```
object(stdClass)[1181]
  public 'kind' => string 'plus#person' (length=11)
  public 'etag' => string '...' (length=57)
  public 'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
  public 'urls' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[1178]
          public 'value' => string '...' (length=35)
          public 'type' => string 'otherProfile' (length=12)
          public 'label' => string 'Picasa Web Albums' (length=17)
  public 'objectType' => string 'person' (length=6)
  public 'id' => string '...' (length=21)
  public 'displayName' => string '...' (length=15)
  public 'name' => 
    object(stdClass)[1183]
      public 'familyName' => string '...' (length=6)
      public 'givenName' => string '...' (length=8)
  public 'url' => string 'https://plus.google.com/...' (length=45)
  public 'image' => 
    object(stdClass)[1180]
      public 'url' => string '...' (length=98)
      public 'isDefault' => boolean false
  public 'placesLived' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[1184]
          public 'value' => string '...' (length=13)
          public 'primary' => boolean true
  public 'isPlusUser' => boolean true
  public 'language' => string 'en' (length=2)
  public 'circledByCount' => int 26
  public 'verified' => boolean false
```

Also tried full scope URL (doesn't change a thing) and "plus.profile.emails.read" that the documentation mentions, but that gives me an invalid scope error.

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: Added the response to the opening post (just hid some personal stuff obviously).

Comment: If the user hasn't set there email to public in Google plus you aren't going to be able to access it.

Comment: @DaImTo If `email` scope is granted you can get the email of the current user regardless of it being public/private.

Comment: Does the [app](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) have "access to basic account info" and "view your email address" listed?

Comment: Only the former. I tried deleting the access, and requesting it again from my app. I get a "<app name> would like to: View your basic profile info" and that's it. `email` scope seems completely ignored :(

Comment: OK, that was really stupid. I was using `scope` parameter for the access token request, but not when initially redirecting the user to the Google authorization form (the step before). Brain fart. Thanks anyway!